# Is "Edit Summary" not important?

Tags: discussion, edits

So I tend to lurk on SO answering what I can, and helping OP's(as much as my understanding can) to make their questions clearer so the questions can be helpful for future users. But lately I've noticed that after I edit a question or answer where I explain exactly what I changed and why I changed it another edit is made and it keeps my own Edit Summary. This is misleading, I'm not asking for the Edit Summary to be enforced but we should always try to keep things clear and in order. Any input on this?

This question is not meant to discuss if "Edit Summary" is helpful/needed or not, it's more as to why some (sometimes highrep) users don't bother in filling out that small textbox.

Comment: Edit summary is _very_ important when you don't have full editing rights. It tells reviewers what we've changed, and we should add why in the least obvious cases, so they can better review our edits. If after you edit someone is editing with the exact same comment, you probably got yours reviewed as "Appove and Edit" meaning you did a decent edit, but the reviewer saw more to add. I don't think they have an option to change the summary, and if they do... Well, I've never seen any of them change it.

Comment: @Kendra Answering box is just down there vvvvvvvvvv

Comment: So you're saying they cannot update the "Edit Summary"? After editing my edit? @Kendra

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've been having issues with the answering box (at work), so that's until I can get one typed up, tranferred to my phone, then copied and pasted into the app.

Comment: I think the context of my and your question are kinda different @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå since I'm questioning why some users don't add their "Edit Summary"

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Oops, I've already downvoted that time it was posted ;-) Anyways I appreciate your participation here a lot!

Comment: I just answered my own question, I forgot to fill "Edit Summary" just now after editing for reasons as why it wasn't a dupe -_-' @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå

Comment: I don't know if they can actually edit the summary on an "Approve and Edit" review or not, Edrodriguez. I've never had the rep on a site to review edits. That's just something I feel could be a thing, since I've never seen an edit reviewed with an "Approve and Edit" that had a different edit summary. A 2k+ user would have to answer that. Users with full editing priviliges don't have to fill in the box- But it's designed so users under 2k do, to try to get them in the habit of explaining their edits. OPs of posts essentially have full editing on their own posts.

Comment: @Kendra you can change the summary. It just auto-populates it with the approved edit's summary, and it's **really** easy to forget about it.

Comment: I noticed @resueman n_n'

Comment: Edit summaries help reviewers review edits.  If I see something the original editor missed, I will "Improve Edit," but I don't see the need to spend additional time to improve the summary.

Comment: I tend to leave out the edit summary blank when I'm only correcting a number of spelling errors, because in my opinion, it is pretty clear why I edited the post (improving readability). Should I henceforth fill in the edit summary field? (PS: I have full editing privileges.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the title: Yes, they definitely are.

Answering the actual question: It's just an artifact of the way <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> in the review queue prepopulates the summary with the existing summary. (This doesn't make much sense to me, but oh well.) Many reviewers forget to put in their own changes.

Comment: *"Many reviewers forget to put in their own changes."* - Or couldn't be arsed!

Answer (score 2):

> This question is not meant to discuss if "Edit Summary" is helpful/needed or not, it's more as to why some (sometimes highrep) users don't bother in filling out that small textbox.

Well, as for my part, I mostly don't bother to add an explanation (though I add summaries like *"Removed noise"* or similar sometimes, to give the OP a hint).

With rep above 2k the system trusts you, and your edits don't need to be reviewed and approved to be realised.

If you are below 2k rep, it's an important part to add the edit summary, such any reviewers can actually judge if your edits should be accepted or not.

Comment: So high rep users don't need to explain themselves? Reviewers are not the only ones who look at edits. Everyone can look at the edit history. It shouldn't matter if you're barely 2k or 1mill rep, if your edits are meaningful i believe they should be addressed, *added/removed xx characters* doesn't cut it, although I completely understand the trust point

Comment: I think it's only really important for 2k edits if the edit might be controversial  or debated, and you want to give a reason for the edit to clarify why you made the change.

Comment: @edrodriguez I find that half the time I'm editing someone else's post my summaries are pretty cookie cutter: "grammer, formatting" "removed noise".  For this half the summary doesn't really do anything for a 2k user.  But the other half of the time with stuff like "included code from comment" it's still important.  I'll sometimes also explain tag changes since they are often less obvious for those unfamiliar with the tags.

Comment: @edrodriguez No, I don't have to explain, it's completely left on my own behalf, if I think an explanation is necessary or not.

Comment: @edrodriguez Many people don't look at edits.  I think there's so much to do to improve the site, time is better-spent improving what's clearly visible to everyone, instead of spending time writing up behind-the-scenes summaries that few will see or care about.

Comment: @PetahChristian so the ones who care about are to be ignored? I don't think that's what SO is about

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ agree to disagree? :) it's gonna be a never ending argument n_n'

Comment: @edrodriguez SO is not about edit summaries.  It's about finding/providing answers to questions.

Comment: I never said it was about edit summaries, SO is not only about finding answers, SO is a community to grow as a developer/programmer; questions and answers are not the only way to gain knowledge. @PetahChristian

Comment: @edrodriguez I think it's unlikely that my skills will have improved as a developer/programmer, because I happened to read an edit summary.  Honestly, if anyone is putting something "valuable" in the edit summary, they're duplicating what they should be adding in a comment (which *everyone* can see).

Comment: @edrodriguez _"it's gonna be a never ending argument n_n"_ Yes, it's completely opinion based, but I've already chosen a different close reason for your question ;-).

Comment: @PetahChristian or even better an answer.

Comment: All good bud @πάνταῥεῖ :)

Comment: @edrodriguez De Nada, dude ;-) ...

Comment: Hey!!! Yo tambien hablo español! Greetings! @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @edrodriguez Just the minimum it takes to order some _tapas_ and say "hola" or so :-D.

Comment: @edrodriguez: I type fast and don't mind leaving meaningful summaries even with 2k+;  another editor or the OP may learn something from it...